# Using Parse.com with Polymer

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, polymer

I have a problem with editing objects in the Polymer Javascript code from inside a Parse.com function. Right after i added the String "foo" to the array in the Parse.com function it says that it contains an item, but it seems like it never really gets added. Somebody know what is wrong?

```
Polymer({        
    users: [],
    created: function () {
        this.getUsers();
    },
    getUsers: function () {
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        query.find().then(function (objects) {
            this.users = ["foo"];
            alert(this.users.length);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `this` isn't what you think it is, and you need to bind the callback function to the custom element.

```
handleCallback: function(objects) {
  this.users = ["foo"];
},
getUsers: function () {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.find().then(this.handleCallback.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the parse query is asynchronous it leaves the scope of the polymer script.. "this" refers to the window at this point
I had this problem with a project of mine. I eventually just did the query outside of the element and passed the data into it:

```
<user-polymer-element></user-polymer-element>
<script>
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        query.find().then(function (objects) {
            document.querySelector('user-polymer-element').users = ["foo"];
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getUsers: function () {
    var that = this;
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.find().then(function (objects) {
        that.users = ["foo"];
        alert(that.users.length);
    });
}
```

Comment: This would be more helpful if you described in words what this code is, rather than just dropping a code block with no context.